# pointer freed not allocated

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

when I compile this piece of code, the pointer freed not allocated error pops up. Could someone please explain why that is? Thank you!

```
static int make_buffer(FILE *input, char *buffer[]){
  *buffer = (char *)malloc(INIT_BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char));

  int buffer_size = INIT_BUFFER_SIZE;
  int txt_size = 0;

  char cha;
  while((cha = fgetc(input)) != EOF){
    if (txt_size == buffer_size){
      *buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, buffer_size*2*sizeof(char));
      buffer_size *= 2;
    }
    (*buffer)[txt_size] = cha;
    txt_size ++;
  }

  free(*buffer);
  return txt_size;
}
```

Comment: The bug is most likely in the caller, which probably also calls `free` on the buffer. (Also, what's the point in returning a dead pointer to memory you've freed?)

Comment: Because it's also passed to the caller. So now you're passing the caller a garbage pointer. If the caller wasn't freeing it, freeing it yourself is the worst possible fix. Now instead of just a leak, you have an access after free!

Comment: that was exactly the problem, thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the code is attempting to free something that was not allocated using malloc/realloc.  In your case, I think the problem is in

```
*buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, buffer_size*2*sizeof(char));
```

which should be

```
*buffer = realloc(*buffer, buffer_size*2);
```

Probably also want to check the result of realloc just for form.   Note I simplified yours a bit in that sizeof(char) == 1 by definition and the cast shouldn't be needed these days (it used to be).  The commend by David S. about the usefulness of freeing the result is also valid.